# WPF checkbox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, checkbox

While it is trivial to store a checkbox's checked state in a variable using the checkbox's Click event, how would I do it via databinding?  All the examples I have found have the UI updated from some datasource, or bind one control to another; I want to update a member variable when the checkbox is clicked.

TIA for any pointers...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need a dependency property for this:

```
public BindingList<User> Users
{
    get { return (BindingList<User>)GetValue(UsersProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UsersProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty UsersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Users", typeof(BindingList<User>), 
      typeof(OptionsDialog));
```

Once that is done, you bind the checkbox to the dependency property:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox"
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=window1, Path=CheckBoxIsChecked}" />
```

For that to work you have to name your Window or UserControl in its openning tag, and use that name in the ElementName parameter.

With this code, whenever you change the property on the code side, you will change the textbox. Also, whenever you check/uncheck the textbox, the Dependency Property will change too.

EDIT:

An easy way to create a dependency property is typing the snippet propdp, which will give you the general code for Dependency Properties.

All the code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTests.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" x:Name="window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <CheckBox Margin="10"
                      x:Name="myCheckBox"
                      IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=window1, Path=IsCheckBoxChecked}">
                Bound CheckBox
            </CheckBox>
            <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=window1, Path=IsCheckBoxChecked}"
                   ContentStringFormat="Is checkbox checked? {0}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace StackOverflowTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public bool IsCheckBoxChecked
        {
           get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckBoxCheckedProperty); }
           set { SetValue(IsCheckBoxCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for 
         //IsCheckBoxChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckBoxCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsCheckBoxChecked", typeof(bool), 
            typeof(Window1), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        public Window1()
        {             
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the only code behind is the Dependency Property. Both the label and the checkbox are bound to it. If the checkbox changes, the label changes too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It appears "ElementName" was the missing key ingredient.

Comment: This will work, but it's not true that "you need a dependency property for this."  See solutions below... all you need is a property on your viewmodel to bind to.

Answer (score 107):

You must make your binding bidirectional :

```
<checkbox IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that sorted it for me, I was using the Content property.

Answer (score 20):

Hello this is my first time posting so please be patient:
my answer was to create a simple property:

```
public bool Checked { get; set; }
```

Then to set the data context of the Checkbox (called cb1):

```
cb1.DataContext = this;
```

Then to bind the IsChecked proerty of it in the xaml

```
IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"
```

The code is like this:

**XAML**

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cb1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="439,81,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="35" Width="96"
          IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cb1.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void myyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Checked.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Should be easier than that.  Just use:

```
<Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding Path=myVar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have the property "MyProperty" on your data-class, then you bind the IsChecked like this....  (the converter is optional, but sometimes you need that)

```
<Window.Resources>
<local:MyBoolConverter x:Key="MyBoolConverterKey"/>
</Window.Resources>
<checkbox IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyBoolConverterKey}}"/>
```

Comment: yup, thats why its "optional" :-)

Comment: <checkbox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked, Mode=TwoWay}"

public bool Checked { get {return _isChecked;} set {_isChecked=value;} }

No joy; _isChecked is never changed.

Comment: check your DataContext then, i am using this myself and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (essential code only included, fill more for your needs):

In XAML a user control is defined:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Mockup.TestTab" ......>
    <!-- a checkbox somewhere within the control -->
    <!-- IsChecked is bound to Property C1 of the DataContext -->
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox 1" IsChecked="{Binding C1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl>
```

In code behind for UserControl

```
public partial class TestTab : UserControl
{
    public TestTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  // the standard bit

    // then we set the DataContex of TestTab Control to a MyViewModel object
    // this MyViewModel object becomes the DataContext for all controls
         // within TestTab ... including our CheckBox
         DataContext = new MyViewModel(....);
    }

}
```

Somewhere in solution class MyViewModel is defined

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool m_c1 = true;

    public bool C1 {
        get { return m_c1; }
        set {
            if (m_c1 != value) {
                m_c1 = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("C1"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No backend and ViewModel Code:**

I made such check box to control other control's visibility.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="rulerCheckbox" Content="Is Ruler Visible" IsChecked="True"/>
```

and in the other control, I added such binding:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rulerCheckbox, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisConverter}}">
```