# WPF How to set checkbox IsChecked binding in code behind

Tags: wpf

I have a style that I have to create in code-behind. It has a checkbox that looks like this..

```
<CheckBox 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataItem.IsChecked}"
              >
</CheckBox>
```

How do I replicate this in code-behind?

Comment: Take a look at Carlos' answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870163/wpf-simple-checkbox-binding-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox();
myCheckBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
myCheckBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
myCheckBox.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, "DataItem.IsChecked");
```

Comment: `myCheckBox.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, "DataItem.IsChecked");` doesn't work. I think its `CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty`.

Comment: IsCheckedProperty is defined in the ToggleButton class. CheckBox is derived from ToggleButton. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't recognize `ToggleButton` as a class. But this works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCheckBox = new CheckBox() {DataContext = DataItem };
myCheckBox.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding(nameof(DataItem.IsChecked));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it