# Why might wpf check box binding fail to work?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Several answers to questions about check box binding, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870743/259) suggest that

```
<checkbox IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

should work. What have I missed in the following code, which does not work?

```
<Window x:Class="TestBinding.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">CheckBox</CheckBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
namespace TestBinding
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        bool property = true;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return property;
            }
            set
            {
                property = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*update*

3 good answers, many thanks, I'd like to accept them all, but have accepted the first that mentioned DataContext which was the part that affected the binding direction I was most interested in. The TwoWay mode has turned out to be a red herring.
And thanks for the MVVM suggestions, I am using it but wanted this code to be as simple as possible

Comment: You should support INotifyPropertyChanged interface in order to keep binding working

Comment: `Binding` keyword works only with the `DataContext` property. I would move the MyProperty property to a view model and bind it to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and set the DataContext to "this" :

```
namespace TestBinding
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(String _Prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_Prop));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        bool property = true;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public bool MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return property;
            }
            set
            {
                property = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your DataContext to the Object that contains the properties the xaml is bound to. In your case, just put `Datacontext = this;` in the c'tor. As well as implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and RaisePropertyChange from every bound property.

As others already said, better to use the MVVM pattern, in which you store the properties in a separate class instead of the UI code behind.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and bind the DataContext to this, then it should work.

You can find msdn link here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

However you should look on the pattern MVVM to handle your wpf/silverlight windows. It will make your life easier: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel