# How to bind value from Dictionary, which is struct, in XAML c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary, binding

I have dictionary which has string for key and struct for value. Struct is:

```
 public class AtributesOfCheckBox
    {
        public string signalName { get; set; }
        public bool checked_value { get; set; }
    }
```

How to bind Name for checkBox with signalName from this dictionary in XAML? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF checkbox binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870163/wpf-checkbox-binding)

Answer (score 0):

Use Gridview or Formview :

Dictionary> _results

GridView myGrid = new GridView();
GridViewColumn gc = new GridViewColumn();

gc.Header = "FileName";

gc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Key");
myGrid.Columns.Add(gc);