# ListView CheckBox IsCheck binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox DataContext="{Binding}" Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" IsChecked=??"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

How can I set my IsChecked to return SomeList.Contains(Item)

Comment: You should have a look to this SO question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870163/wpf-checkbox-binding

Comment: Binding to a single property works fine, I am confused because this is in a listView

Comment: In MVVM you would typically make a property which produces result you need and then simply bind to it. It's not clear what is `Item` maybe you can use converter with `ConverterParameter="{Binding Item}"`.

Comment: Not nearly enough code here to tell. What is the list view bound to? What type is SomeList?