# Boolean and Array trouble

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, boolean

I have a problem with a method.
I have checkboxes to change the value of variables to true / false.

My variables Prise1, Prise2, Prise3 and Prise4 on one side, and on the other side on the 7 days of the week.

I have to complete a request that is made in relation to the selected days. For example:

[image: example]

On the screenshot, I would like to modify the information about:

- Tuesday, Wednesday of "prise1"
- nothin on "prise2"
- on Friday and Sunday of "prise3"
- Thursday of "duration"

I thought of a 2D table that I could go through to check if the values are true / false, but I don't really know how to do it.

Edit : 
Did i miss something ? Binding doesn't work, when i check i'm not going into the "set".

```
    public class WeekValues : ObservableObject
{
    public bool Monday { get; set; }
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
    public bool Saturday { get; set; }
    public bool Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

For the viewModel :

```
        private WeekValues _Prise1;
    public WeekValues Prise1
    {
        get
        {
            return _Prise1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Prise1)
            {
                _Prise1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prise1));
            }
        }
    }

    private WeekValues _Prise2;
    public WeekValues Prise2
    {
        get
        {
            return _Prise2;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Prise2)
            {
                _Prise2 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prise2));
            }
        }
    }
```

and WPF :

```
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,9,0,5" IsChecked="{Binding Prise1}"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,10,0,5" IsChecked="{Binding Prise2.Monday}"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,10,0,5"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,9,0,0"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">M</Label>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,9,0,5" IsChecked="{Binding Prise1.Tuesday}"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,10,0,5" IsChecked="{Binding Prise2.Tuesday}"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,10,0,5"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,9,0,0"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it windows forms or wpf?

Comment: it's wpf, with MVVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a custom type instead of an array in your ViewModel?

```
internal class WeekValues : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool Monday { get {... } set { ...} }
    public bool Tuesday { get {... } set { ...} }
    public bool Wednesday { get {... } set { ...} }
    public bool Thursday { get {... } set { ...} }
    public bool Friday { get {... } set { ...} }
    public bool Saturday { get {... } set { ...} }
    public bool Sunday{ get {... } set { ...} }

    ...
}

internal class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public WeekValues Prise1 { get {... } set { ...} }
    public WeekValues Prise2 { get {... } set { ...} }
    public WeekValues Prise3 { get {... } set { ...} }
    public WeekValues Duree { get {... } set { ...} }

    ...
}
```

Than for each `CheckBox` you could write:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Prise1.Monday}" />
```

But a better solution would be to create a `UserControl` for all week values with 7 `CheckBoxes` in it. The `UserControl` could have a `DependencyProperty` of type `WeekValues`. This way your main xaml could look like this:

```
<MyWeekValuesUserControl WeekValues="{Binding Prise1}" />
<MyWeekValuesUserControl WeekValues="{Binding Prise2}" />
<MyWeekValuesUserControl WeekValues="{Binding Prise3}" />
<MyWeekValuesUserControl WeekValues="{Binding Duree}" />
```

What is more, if Prise1, Prise2, Prise3, Duree list is dynamic, you could use an `ItemsControl`.

How to create an `UserControl` you can find in [this blog post](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/usercontrols-and-customcontrols/creating-using-a-usercontrol/)

Comment: The `WeekValues` class is definitely the way to go. UI-wise, I'd probably use an `ItemsControl` with `SharedSizeGroup` grids instead of a user control.

Comment: Your solution seems to be the right one even if it makes me add a class to the project I'm on, it must be possible. but if you tell me that the best thing would be to use a "UserControl", I'll see if I can understand how it works. Thank you for the link!

Comment: Doesnt work for me right now, maybe i miss something ? the biding doesn't seem to work, nothing is happening. I may have made a mistake, I'm editing my code, could you please look at it?

Comment: Sure. In WeekValues you should also call RaisePropertyChanged().

Comment: Another hint: As I can see, you have ObservableObject. If it comes from one of known frameworks, you could probably use Set method instead of calling RaisePropertyChanged. Take a look here when you figure it all out :) http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-toolkit-example

Comment: Also, some more examples of CheckBox binding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31029460/1319086 . If this is your first time with Binding, maybe try with a simpler example. Something like a single window with a single view model and a single checkbox :)

Comment: I think this question is answered completly. If possible, try to ask a new question for your next trouble, to avoid editing this one.